# passing array to a function php

Tags: php, arrays, forms, argument-passing

I am getting information from an html form using var_export.

```
$info = var_export($_POST);

echo '<pre>';
$info;
echo '</pre>';
```

When I print out the contents of $info this is the output:

array ( 'name' => 'a', 'address' => 'b', 'city' => 'c', 'state' => 'd', 'zip' => '1', 'phone' => '2', 'open' => '3', 'close' => '4', )

which is correct, but when I pass that variable to a function:

```
validate($info);
function validate($data){
    echo "Hello";
    echo '<pre>';
    $data;
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

and try to print the contents again it does not print anything. I know it is going into the function because "Hello" gets printed. What is happening here?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What do you think `var_export()` does?

Comment: @zerkms i see where i messed up, I believed that var_export automatically returned the variable representation, now I see that it has to be set to true for that, thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function validate($data){
  echo "Hello";
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($data);
  echo '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$data;
```

Doesn't do anything.

Try `print_r($data);` or for an individual array element `echo $data['name'];`

Comment: One more thing - there is `NULL` in `$info`

Comment: I'll try that but why did it work earlier outside of the function? It printed to the html page

Comment: @Ameya: because `var_export` prints that. Have you read the manual page about it? http://php.net/var_export

Answer (score 1):

First off, just putting the variable there will not output it (to my knowledge).  `echo`ing it won't work either because it'll just output the type `Array`.  You'll want to use either [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution:

```
validate($info);
function validate($data){
    echo "Hello";
    echo '<pre>';

    // Start capturing output
    ob_start();

    // var_dump() outputs the string.
    var_dump( $data );

    // print out everything captured since last call to ob_start()
    echo ob_get_clean();

    echo '</pre>';
}
```

The ob_start() starts to capture any output.  The ob_get_clean(), dumps any output to a string.  Doing this will print out exactly what you see when you do a var_dump( $data ).

Answer (score 0):

`var_export` combines the functions of turning your array into a string, and printing the data. You cannot print data (or "echo") it by just placing the variable in the script as you're doing with your `$info;` line.

If you want to view the contents of an array, as they are, use `print_r($array)` as stated before. If you want to view the string you've created using `var_export()`, use `echo $data;`.

`print_r($data);` will not work as has been stated as in your case `$data` is not an array but a string.

Here is what I would do:

```
function validate($data){
    echo "Hello!";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";
}

validate($_POST); // since you actually must call the function after it's been declared
```